# string not recognized as valid dateTime, when it appears?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime

I'm getting the error `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`

When I debug through the code at the line:

```
DateTime targetDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TargetDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Holding the cursor over `TargetDate` displays today's date 'Thu 19 December'.

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Comment: **ParseExact** requires the string be **exactly** as your date mask

Answer (score 4):

> Holding the cursor over 'TargetDate' displays todays date 'Thu 19 December'

Well that explains it.

The string "Thu 19 December" is not in the form "yyyy-MM-dd" is it?

You could specify a format string of "ddd dd MMMM" but that wouldn't specify where the year should be fetched from. It's not at all clear where `TargetDate` is coming from, but if you can possibly change the format of *that* to something more sensible (such as the yyyy-MM-dd you're currently attempting to parse it as) that would be much cleaner.